# i want to select float value from database and show the result in textbox (asp.net)?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I want to fetch float data (if exist) from database and after addition show the result in text box (`TXT_grandtotal`)

In my code its shows only numeric value

```
double price= 0;   
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmd.CommandText = "select total from productADD where auto_no='"+txt_autoNo.Text.Trim() + "'";
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    float id = (Convert.ToInt32(row["total"]));
    price = id + price;
    TXT_grandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToString(price));
}
```

Comment: Is total in float type?  because this line  `float id = (Convert.ToInt32(row["total"]));` is confusing

Comment: You use `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `Convert.ToSingle()`. And btw: please don't insert user input directly into your query, use **paramterized queries** instead. Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://www.bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading the duplicate link on SQL Injection. Then, read up on Dapper.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `row["total"]`?

Comment: lbl_nuToword.Text = NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(TXT_grandtotal.Text)); when i want to show the result in word its says the string is not in correct format ?

Comment: That is a new question. `NumberToWords` is not in your question. Please write a new question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
           cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(CAST(total AS int)) AS total from productADD where auto_no='"+txt_autoNo.Text.Trim() + "'";

            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);

            TXT_grandtotal.Text=Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["total"]);
```

**Note:-- You can Follow this method...here i'm Calculating the total Value...instead of using for Loop...**

**This will improve your performance..**

**you can use cast if your table data type as varchar**

Comment: i will try this one also

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection - for other readers **do not use this answer**.

Answer (score 2):

First issue in your code is that you are not using parametrize query, secondly conversion was not correct, please check the following code if it help you

```
double price= 0;   
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string sql = "select total from productADD where auto_no = @auto_no";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
{
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@auto_no", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@auto_no"].Value = Int32.Parse(txt_autoNo.Text.Trim());
}

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    float id = (Convert.ToSingle(row["total"]));
    float price = id + price;
    TXT_grandtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(price)
}
```